# Incorporating Java Styles in code preview

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating a website where you have a text area to write java code and need to incorporate java style colors for classes, keywords etc.. just like a normal java editor would provide. Is there a plug-in kind of a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google shows [CodePress](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress/). This is not so much a java/jsp question as a html/javascript question.